# #ERROR in User-Defined Field Formula Even After Testing Against ProjDateValue('NA')

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I've been struggling with a Microsoft Project (2013 Standard) formula assigned to a number user-defined field to calculate the difference between tasks' current Finishes and a baseline Finish I've previously set.

> ```
> Switch(
> [Finish]="",0,
> [Baseline1 Finish]="",0,
> [Finish]=projdatevalue('NA'),0,
> [Baseline1 Finish]=projdatevalue('NA'),0,
> [Finish]-[Baseline1 Finish]<=0,0,
> [Finish]-[Baseline1 Finish]>0,[Finish]-[Baseline1 Finish]
> )
> ```

On tasks for which [Baseline1 Finish] is "NA" I consistently get a #ERROR, even though I should have trapped for it between lines 3 & 5 above. I've tried everything I can think of, such as:

- Using an equivalent IIF formula
- Using different user-defined date fields (e.g., [Baseline2 Finish])
- Removing different elements of the formula one at a time
- Checking against a "high" date value (e.g., 2^30, since this is how I understand Project actually renders "NA" behind the scenes) instead of using ProjDateValue (c.f. http://masamiki.com/project/customfieldFAQ.htm)

But no seeming change in behavior.  **Is there a defect in Project when using ProjDateValue in a formula against one of the user-defined date fields?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few things to note:

- Instead of checking the task Finish field for N/A or 0, use the `IsDate` function.
- While N/A values for date fields are internally stored as very large integers (2^32) you only need to test against something greater than Project's maximum date (which appears to be #12/31/2099# for Project 2013; #12/31/2049# for earlier versions). Testing against a large integer (e.g. 2^30) might lead to an overflow error.
- Use the `ProjDateDiff` function to calculate the difference between two dates. If you don't supply the third parameter (calendar) the project calender is used (which is almost always what you want).
- Use a Duration field to hold the results of this formula.

This **updated** formula should work for you:

```
IIf([Baseline1 Finish]>75000 Or Not IsDate([Finish]),0,ProjDateDiff([Finish],[Baseline1 Finish]))
```

If desired, you can modify it to force negative deltas to be zero (as you had in your original formula).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Rachel. When you said "The task Finish field is always a date, so you don't have to check it for N/A or 0" it seems contrary to advice I've seen on multiple web sites to overcome this exact type of issue (c.f. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/71ae82f4-d58a-46ef-b8d2-1c1a3e9a654a/how-do-i-avoid-error-results-in-microsoft-project-formulas?forum=projectprofessional2010general).

Comment: As for the question around overflow when comparing - I was concerned about that as well, but that was just in one of techniques I tried and it did not seem to help nor hurt.

Comment: I was using a number user-defined field for the result (which except for the #ERROR cases, produced the correct number) - so I tried a duration user-defined field.  It did not change the #ERROR behavior (although it didn't produce the correct numeric result).

Comment: I did try your formula which works (and works "better" since it calculates based upon project days, not days of the week) for the same items - but there are Finish dates that I've actually deleted in the plan (at least from the UI - no idea what Project does under the scenes) and those are now throwing errors.  You've given me some more ideas to try - I'll give those a go and report back on what I find.

Comment: @JimMSDN I stand corrected on the use of the `Finish` field in custom field formulas; see my updated formula above. It is in fact using the same Finish as you see in the UI which can be text instead of a date. (I spend 99% of my time writing code and there the `Finish` field is **always** a date whereas the `FinishText` field stores what is seen in the UI.)

Comment: That did the trick. I reversed the order of the ProjDateDiff operands and checked for negative (i.e., ahead of schedule) deltas to get `IIf([Baseline1 Finish]>2^30 Or Not IsDate([Finish]),0,IIf(ProjDateDiff([Baseline1 Finish],[Finish])<0,0,ProjDateDiff([Baseline1 Finish],[Finish])))`. Thanks for the insights - not much info out there on complex Project formulas!

Comment: Just a quick comment.  With the introduction in Project 2010 of manually scheduled tasks - you are better looking at the Scheduled Finish or Scheduled Start for tasks.  They always have a date - even if it is a manually scheduled tasks with text typed in the Start or Finish field.

Comment: Another comment - Project calculates finish variance (difference between finish and baseline finish) for you, so you can let Project do the heavy lifting and just test for the value in finish variance.

Comment: Good thought @JulieS as I had thought about using finish variance, but I've got multiple baselines reflecting various points in the project and was needing a flexible way to report against these different BLs.

Comment: You can change which baseline is used for Finish variance in File > Options, Advanced - under Earned Value Method.

Answer (score 1):

@JimMSDN -- This is an old thread but I would like to add for the future readers: it works differently in formulas. So in MS Project 2010 and later, the Finish field can be blank. And the Baseline Finish can be blank as well. There is a new field Baseline Estimated Finish. But you must first decide whether you want formula to work for both manually scheduled and automatically scheduled tasks. Please see [Working with Manually Scheduled Tasks](http://www.msptips.com/Formulas/_Working%20with%20Manually%20Scheduled%20Tasks.html) and [Errors in Formulas](http://www.msptips.com/Formulas/_Errors%20in%20Formulas.html). Regards -- Ismet

Answer (score 0):

There is built in Field in MS project for that Finish variance, which will give you variance between, baseline and current finish date.